# How to access Request headers in Spring Web services PayloadValidatingInterceptor

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-ws

I am currently working on a Spring Web services(SOAP) project. The requirement is to validate the request payload and return the error response if validation fails and log it. I have extended PayloadValidatingInterceptor to return custom validation message.

As part of logging requirement, we need to print the header values from Request Headers (HttpServletRequest) for tracking purpose.

How to access HttpServletRequest in the implementation of PayloadValidatingInterceptor?
Is it possible to inject HttpServletRequest?

version details:

```
Spring-Boot : 2.2.6
Spring-ws-core : 3.0.8
```

Please help.

Comment: It isn't because it doesn't know about the transport. Could be HTTP, JMS, FILE, Email etc. You can obtain the `WebServiceConnection` through the `TransportContextHolder` and check if it is an `HeadersAwareReceiverWebServiceConnection` and obtain the headers that way. However if you want to log HTTP requests you are probably better of using a filter instead of shoehorning it into a validator.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you for your quick response and answering my question.